# Python: Undefined variable in nested function when variable exists in parent function?

Tags: python, function, api

Edit: I realize this isn't a nested function, instead I'm calling a function within a function!

I am pulling data from 5 different endpoints (endpoint_a through endpoint_e) and each endpoint has its own function `get_endpoint_` such as below:

```
def get_endpoint_a() -> pd.dataFrame:
    """
    Return data from API endpoint.

    Includes all data. It is initially returned as a JSON and
    then transformed into a DataFrame.
    """
    url = configs.ENDPOINT_A
    querystring = configs.a_querystring
    try:
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=header, params=querystring)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        raise sys.exit(e)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(f"Response from API: {response.status_code}")

    response = response.json()
    return _get_all_data(response)
```

And I have a sub function `_get_all_data` to append the results along with a whilr loop for pagination as defined below:

```py
def _get_all_data(response):
    """
    Return the results of the get request.

    Loops over api response and appends results to list in addition to appending the
    results of a while loop for pagination.
    """
    results = []
    for x in response["results"]:
        results.append(x)
    while response["paging"]["next"]["link"] is not None:
        url = response["paging"]["next"]["link"]
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=header, params=querystring)

        response = response.json()

        for x in response["results"]:
            results.append(x)
    return json_normalize(results)
```

When I run the functions in Jupyter it works, however when I run the code through a linter I'm getting an `undefined variable "querystring"` error message referring to the `params=querystring` in the sub function. Given that each endpoint requires a different querystring, I'm unable to define it globally and using `nonlocal` returns `unable to parse` or `nonlocal variable must be bound in outer function scope`.

Could anyone help me or point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't see any nested functions.

Comment: Oops, you're right! I meant I'm calling a function within a function!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in a comment, this isnt a nested function. However, to fix your problem you just need to add `querystring` as an argument to your function and pass it in each time:

```
def _get_all_data(response, querystring):
"""
Return the results of the get request.

Loops over api response and appends results to list in addition to appending the
results of a while loop for pagination.
"""
results = []
for x in response["results"]:
    results.append(x)
while response["paging"]["next"]["link"] is not None:
    url = response["paging"]["next"]["link"]
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=header, params=querystring)

    response = response.json()

    for x in response["results"]:
        results.append(x)
return json_normalize(results)


def get_endpoint_a() -> pd.dataFrame:
    """
    Return data from API endpoint.

    Includes all data. It is initially returned as a JSON and
    then transformed into a DataFrame.
    """
    url = configs.ENDPOINT_A
    querystring = configs.a_querystring
    try:
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=header, params=querystring)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        raise sys.exit(e)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(f"Response from API: {response.status_code}")

    response = response.json()
    return _get_all_data(response, querystring)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! This helped! You're right, it's not nested! I meant to say I'm calling a function within a function! I appreciate your help!